# Slow migration to Visual Studio Online from TFS 2013.4 (OpsHub)

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying to migrate from TFS 2013 Update 4 to Visual Studio Online.  I have had real difficulties using OpsHub Migration Utility, so I have come now seeking advice on how I may go forward.
I have 65 Team Projects to migrate, some with source code, others fairly empty with just a few work items so they differ in size a fair bit.  I want to maintain branches we currently have which are cross Team Projects so I initially tried selecting all 65 projects for migration.  This took 11hours at the creating configuration stage of the utility, then on getting to the end the tool complained it could not communicate with the service OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility.  So back to square one.
Next approach was to batch the projects into sets of 10 projects. The validation and creating configuration stage was done in 10mins for each set which was a big leap forward, and the migration actually started.  This has currently been running for about 17hours.  It has done 29,000 work item revisions out of 480,000 across all Team Projects, so I think this may well take a couple of weeks to clear.  It hasn't started on the Version Control data yet, which I'm hopeful it does at a later stage but this says not running at the moment.
This is running on a fast i7 box, with 16GB RAM, SSDs the business. 100Mbps internet connection.
I have emailed OpsHub to find out if the commercial version will perform better.  But any suggestions what I could do better welcome, including any alternatives to the migration tool.

Answer (score 2):

- For Configuration creation taking high time, the assumed reason seems
  to be due to issue in communicating with the service OpsHub Visual
  Studio Online and waiting till the TimeOut.
- The Work Item migration sync time seems to be near to the expectation, migration of Version Control data will be started once the work item migration is completed.
- Also as the data is in big amount, its taking time but the migration would keep on running in background, you can use your source TFS instance(if required) without stopping the migration.
- For more details on Profession Services you can drop an email to support@opshub.com

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, you say keep using the source TFS instance.  Is the migration smart enough to migrate new code changes and work items that are created while the migration happens?  I wouldn't have expected this, and this is one reason why this taking weeks isn't a great solution for us.  We are only a small team.

Comment: Yes, the utility is perfectly fine running in the background. And will detect and migrate all the new changes created in the projects while the migration is running, as long as the migration is running and not stopped.

Comment: That is great news.  Can I ask does the free utility maintain branches that are cross team project? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes. Provided, all the projects have been selected together in a single migration. Across project linkage and branching will be retained.

Comment: V2 of the migration tool only allows one project to be selected, does that mean this is now unsupported or have I misunderstood? Thank you for your support.

Comment: Aah. I am afraid, yes. The support for multi-project has been recently removed from the free version of the utility.

Answer (score 0):

There is another tool named [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) that developed by MS for TFS Migration. You can try with it to see if it can migrate the data faster.

Comment: Thanks Eddie, I can't see reference to using this with Visual Studio Online (Team System) unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnCorker, you can just select the Team System provider to connect to Visual Studio Online.